# Facebook liked URL - Difference between Graph API and FQL query

Tags: url, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-fql

I am a bit confused between 2 different results.

When I want to retrieve a list of the liked URL with the graph :

```
$url="https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes?access_token=".$access_token;
```

**The result is** : everything I liked and they all have an id.

Than I tried to retrieve the liked URL with fql :

```
 $fql_query_url="SELECT url FROM url_like WHERE user_id = me()";  
 $query = "https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=";
```

**The result is** : many different URLS (most of them are youtube ones) and some of them doesn't have an id

My questions are :

- What is the difference between these 2 requests ?
- Why some of the fql responses have an id and others not ?
- How can I get all the liked URL who have an id ?

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `/me/likes` connection of the Graph API user object only contains likes for **Facebook pages**; where as the `url_likes` FQL table contains the **Open Graph URLs** the user liked, as is stated in the [description](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/url_like/):

> *“An FQL table containing the Open Graph URLs that a user has Liked.”*

Open Graph URLs in general don’t have their own Facebook ids; they themselves “are” their own id – `http://example.com/` identifies `http://example.com/` in the Open Graph, and the Facebook data for that URL can be accessed by that, http://graph.facebook.com/http://example.com/